# what is the right regex?

Tags: java, regex

I try to find a regex in order to extract the name of a file. My String is `path/string.mystring`

for exemple

```
totot/tototo/tatata.tititi/./com.myString
```

I try to get `myString`.

I tried  `String[] test = foo.split("[*.//./.]");`

Comment: Its answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011287/get-file-name-from-a-file-location-in-java

Comment: OP doesn't actually want the name of the file, just a part of it

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011287/get-file-name-from-a-file-location-in-java). I would say that using a regex to get the file name  is the wrong way to go (for example, if your code ever tries to run against a Windows file path the slashes in your regex will be the wrong way round) - why not just use:

```
new File(fileName).getName();
```

to get the name of the file, and then extract the part of the file name that you want using a simpler split:

```
String[] fileNameParts = foo.split("\\.");
String partThatYouWant = fileNameParts [fileNameParts.length - 1];
```

Comment: That will get you `com.myString`, not `myString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last word with this: `\w+$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on period or slash, the regex should be

```
foo.split("[/\\.]")
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
String name = foo.substring(foo.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> My String is path/string.mystring

If your string pattern is fixed following the rule above, how about:

```
string.replaceAll(".*\\.","")
```

Answer (score 0):

A **non-regex solution** using `String#subString`& `String#lastIndexOf` would be.

```
String path="totot/tototo/tatata.tititi/./com.myString";
String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just use the String API. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String path = "totot/tototo/tatata.tititi/./com.myString";
    System.out.println(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
}
```

Does it fit your case? There are many problems in working with indexes. But if you're always sure there will be a `.` you can use this without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Regexp
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    String x = "totot/tototo/tatata.tititi/./com.myString";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "[a-z0-9A-Z]+$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);

    while (matcher.find()) 
        {
        System.out.format("Text found in x: => \"%s\"\n",
                  matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```