# Extract file name from the URL

Tags: java, file, extension-methods

Eg. http://www.example.com/
How to extract the index file extension from above URL?

Tried with getpath method of URL class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get file name from a file location in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011287/get-file-name-from-a-file-location-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/file.ext?query";
String file = new URL(url).getFile();
String lastFile = file.substring(file.lastIndex('/')+1);
int pos = lastFile.lastIndex('.');
String ext = pos > 0
           ? lastFile.substring(pos + 1) 
           : NONE;
```

Note: your original example has neither a file nor an extension.

Comment: -1 would not work with URLs like the ones used in Web API
"http://www.example.com/api/products" would return "com/api/products"

Comment: @JhonAlx that's not a URL.  The browser changes this to `http://www.example.com/api/products%22`

Comment: @JhonAlx Here is more documentation on what a URL is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

Comment: From the Wiki article: *A typical URL might look like:

http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page*

Comment: @JhonAlx and if I copy the URL from by browser it says it is `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`

Comment: @JhonAlx if you send `GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.0` to this server, you get a page back but if you send `GET en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.0` you get a 400 error stating `Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.`

Comment: Let the code speak for the point I'm trying to prove: http://ideone.com/3pWncb, extensionless URL would return complete path 

P.S.: In my first comment the correct return value would be "/api/products"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69249/discussion-between-jhonalx-and-peter-lawrey).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for content type in http headers which will tell you the type of response.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm trying to build a Crawler like application which will extract all the hyperlinks on a page and visit each crawled hyperlink in an iterative fashion..