# How can I check, whether a file name exists in a directory?

Tags: java, eclipse

My program is simply reading 2 values and then doing some operations with these. (This part is not important.) In the beginning I have to check file name. For example my program starts with

> Enter the file name:

When I enter the file name, my program should check whether or not a file with this name exists in the project workspace. I have a file in project library and I want to check: "Is this file name same or not with given name by user".

```
 String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

I can get the workspace location with this code.

```
 File a = new File(" --Workspace direction-- ");
 if(filename.equals(a.getName())){

 }
```

I created a new file and tried to compare with `.getName()` method. The problem is I think in the workspace location the .txt file name is missing. When I get the workpace location with first code I just have

> /Users/asd/Documents/workspace/project/

this. But to be able to get the file name, there should be the file name at the end of that file path. How can I check, whether or not a file exists  in the workspace directory with the name given by the user input?

Comment: I can't understand anything to your question. What do you mean by "workspace direction"? Do you realize that a "workspace" is a concept that only exists in an IDE, on a developer machine? End users don't have any workspace. All they have is your program, that they executed from some directory. That said, I don't even understand what you're trying to achieve. The user enters a file name. Then what?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding .Think like that when I run this java code in my computer there is no problem. I can write a code File a = new File("/Users/asd/Documents/workspace/project/.input.txt" );   and I can easily get the file  name and compare with the input file name . But another computer. /Users/asd/Documents/workspace/project/.input.txt this direction will change. (Sorry for typing mistakes.I'm trying to adjust :) ) @JBNizet

Comment: Please answer my question. Let's say I install your program on my computer. Then I run it. It asks me to enter a file name. I enter "hello.txt". What should the program do, then?

Comment: For example check is there a file with the same name "hello.txt" in your desktop. Your desktop will be my workspace file. Think this is your desktop direction "/Users/JBNizet/Desktop/" but in another computer this direction will be different. In java code I have to write direction for create a new file as I said . When I get the direction the file how can I get the file name in this direction? Think there is just one file in your desktop.

Comment: @karacaoglanb What you are calling a "direction," is usually called a [*file path*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

Comment: The file name will be returned by `file.getName()`, as you have done. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1011287/604687).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume `inputName` contains the input from the user:

```
 /* In your case, this is entered by the user */
 String inputName = "testfile.txt";
```

Then you get your workspace directory:

```
 String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Now you want to know, whether a file named "testfile.txt" exists in that workspace directory. Create a File instance for such a file:

```
 // a File instance for the directory:
 File workingDirFile = new File(workingDir); 
 // a File instance for a file in that directory:
 File testfile = new File(workingDirFile, inputName);
```

Now you should have `workingDirFile` which contains "/Users/asd/Documents/workspace/project/" and `testfile` which contains "/Users/asd/Documents/workspace/project/testfile.txt" .
To check, whether the file exists:

```
 if (testfile.exists()) {
     /* file with name "testfile.txt" exists in project dir */
 } else {
     /* file with name "testfile.txt" does not exist in project dir */
 }
```

Comment: Glad I could help :-) You may want to look at the File javadoc and may want to add more tests. For instance if you only want the user input to match against actual files and not directories, make sure, that the `testfile` is a file and not a directory. (Details are in the javadoc)